# web site cant connect with localhost with http / https addresses

Tags: node.js, http, https, localhost

I'm running node application on local host , the connection established successfully.
when opening my browser (chrome) , I can't connect when the address is
http://localhost:port/ or https://localhost:port
error : This site can’t provide a secure connection.
but when I put the address without http or https , just localhost:port
everything's ok.
I would appreciate any advice.